# List all files in subdirectories sort by subdirectory name

Tags: find, recursive

I have a folder that has many subfolders in it. I want to list all the files in all the subfolders but I want the files sorted by subfolder name. I'm not interested in files in the current directory.

Currently I am using this command which gets me the correct filename & path output I desire, with the exception that it is not sorted by subfolder.

```
find -type f
```

ex data:

```
8585/file10.txt
8585/file83.txt
34032/file130.txt
10/file5400.txt
```

desired sorted output:

```
10/file5400.txt
8585/file83.txt
8585/file10.txt
34032/file130.txt
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the data from `find` into `sort`. The default setting for `sort` is according to your locale, typically alphanumeric. If that's not giving you the sorting order you want, *and* you have GNU `sort`, try with the `-V` flag as in my example,

```
find -type f | sort -V
```

See `man sort` for the details

Comment: worked great! thanks @roaima !!

Answer (score 1):

If you read [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find), you'll see that `find` has a maxdepth option. But its less to type if you just

```
ls */* | sort
```

Comment: this also worked. Not sure if one is better than the other answer. But thank you regardless @symcbean